# Difference in g++ for Mac and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, g++

The following code can be compiled using `g++ x.cpp` in MacOS:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  int y = pow(x, 2) - x + 1;
  std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

In Linux it throw an error because `pow` is not declared. This would be the expected behaviour I guess. g++ should be portable and behave the same regardless of the OS right? Can It be that in Mac it somehow includes the `cmath` library by default?

Comment: Standard headers are allowed to include each other. Also Mac infamously symlinks `g++` to Clang, so maybe that's why you see this difference.

Comment: no. its not "the expected behavior". When you miss an include you can get an error or you can not get an error due to transitive includes.

Comment: Portability means that well-formed code will work on both. It can be that one implementation is including bonus headers in a standard header. But you should not rely on this.

Comment: `pow` ≠ `std::pow`.  `std::pow` is in `#include <cmath>`.  Include the header, and use the **std** version.  Standard headers are allowed to — but not required to (except in a few cases) — include other headers.

Comment: The compiler is required to be happy if you include the correct headers, but it is not required to not be happy if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove the `<iostream>` include, pow is not declared, which suggests a transitive include (as **463035818_is_not_an_ai** commented).
Because this code performs differently between Mac and Linux, I will assume the implementations of the standard library are different, with Mac's including `<cmath>`, and the Linux's not including `<cmath>`. The standard library implementations may differ between compilers, so I assume, as commented by **HolyBlackCat**, my Mac is symlinking gcc to clang.